# simple jcarousel slider doesnt work without auto set to 1

Tags: jquery, navigation, uislider, jcarousel

i made simple slider for changing lists and it works only when I set **auto** to **1**. I need to make it work by clicking on the "*prev*" and "*next*". How can i setup jcarousel() function?

there is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLp7jz3w/1/

**html**

```
<div class="jcarousel">
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

```
<a class="jcarousel-prev" href="javascript:void(0)">prev</a>
<a class="jcarousel-next" href="javascript:void(0)">next</a>
```

**css**

```
.jcarousel {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width:52px;
height:50px;
background-color: cyan;
```

}

```
.jcarousel ul {
width: 270px;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

}

```
.jcarousel li {
float: left;
width:46px;
background-color: yellow;
height:34px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
border: 1px solid gray;
margin: 2px;
```

}

**javascript**

```
    $('.jcarousel-next').click(function () {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
          scroll: -1,
          auto: 1,
          wrap: "circular"
    });
});

$('.jcarousel-prev').click(function () {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
          scroll: 1,
          auto: 1,
          wrap: "circular"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the plugin documentation:

```
<div class="jcarousel">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- You need the data-attribute below -->
<a class="jcarousel-next" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">prev</a>
<!-- You need the data-attribute below -->
<a class="jcarousel-prev" data-jcarouselcontrol="true">next</a>
```

And you initiated the plugin in a wrong way:

```
$(function () {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
        wrap: "circular"
    });

    $('.jcarousel-next').jcarouselControl({
        target: '+=1'
    });

    $('.jcarousel-prev').jcarouselControl({
        target: '-=1'
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/mLp7jz3w/2/)

**Note:** You need to load the `jQuery` library, the `jCarousel` library, then your `script`, in this exactly order. Stick everything in your page header.

Comment: Mark the answer as the solution then. Glad I could help.